# ggplot2: Legend for labeling multiple geom_abline slopes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this `data.frame`, which I have `dput` below, to map three slopes using `geom_abline`:

```
  moderator_value simple_intercept simple_slope
1              -1      -0.02745523    0.2768973
2               0       0.05990693    0.2147829
3               1       0.14726909    0.1526684
```

What I have right now is this code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_abline(data=ablines, 
              mapping=aes(slope=simple_slope, intercept=simple_intercept),
              linetype=c(1,2,3)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1.5,2), name="Prejudice") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-.75, .75), name="Authenticity") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=14))
```

This returns the figure:

[image]

I would like to add a legend that labels these three separate lines by their `linetype`. I have looked elsewhere on SO, but many of these say just to include `show_guide` in the `geom_abline` function (which has now been deprecated in favor of `show.legend`) and set it to `TRUE`. This is not working for me. I've tried to use `scale_linetype_manual`, as well, with no luck.

How can I include a legend that labels each of the lines separately? I'd like to include the moderator variable's name as well as "-1 SD", "Mean", and "+1 SD" as the labels.

`dput` of the `ablines` data:

```
structure(list(moderator_value = c(-1, 0, 1), simple_intercept = c(-0.0274552251655293, 
0.0599069333124192, 0.147269091790368), simple_slope = c(0.276897278474258, 
0.214782863579552, 0.152668448684846)), .Names = c("moderator_value", 
"simple_intercept", "simple_slope"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should try to do is map a unique feature of each line (i.e., the moderator as a factor (b.c. we dont want to interpret it as a continuous variable)) to the linetype.

For example by using this code

```
ablines <- structure(list(moderator_value = c(-1, 0, 1), 
                          simple_intercept = c(-0.0274552251655293, 0.0599069333124192, 0.147269091790368), 
                          simple_slope = c(0.276897278474258, 0.214782863579552, 0.152668448684846)),
                     .Names = c("moderator_value", "simple_intercept", "simple_slope"), 
                     row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ablines) +
 geom_abline(mapping = aes(slope = simple_slope,
                           intercept = simple_intercept, 
                           linetype = as.factor(moderator_value))) +
 scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1.5,2), name="Prejudice") +
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-.75, .75), name="Authenticity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the legend you have to map a variable to the lynetipe within the aes(). In your code you specified it outside the aes(). 
Note that in my code, the numeric value of the variable "moderator" will map that number to ggplot's available line styles.
To give a custom name to each linetype, uncomment the last instruction.

```
ggplot() +
      geom_abline(data=ablines, 
                  mapping=aes(slope=simple_slope, intercept=simple_intercept, linetype = moderator_value)) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1.5,2), name="Prejudice") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-.75, .75), name="Authenticity") +
      theme_light() ## +
      ## scale_linetype_continuous(labels = c("First Line", "Second Line", "Third Line")
```